# Salesforce Partner Security Portal is not listing our package

Tags: apex, 2gp

We are currently in the process of developing a 2G Manage package.

We have a Partner Business Org setup, which is also acting as our dev hub. This was done on the advise of our Salesforce Rep.

Further, to this our development happens in a scratch org. We have linked the dev hub as the org in our partner community also. However, when I login to the Salesforce security portal to run a Checkmarkx scan, no package is shown in the list. I have even tried promoting the package to a released package but still nothing in shown in the security portal.

Could someone please advise what is the issue with our setup?

Comment: Are you certain you created a managed 2GP and not an Unlocked package by mistake?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox yes it is a managed 2GP package. I have installed it other orgs and can cleary see it is managed.

Comment: I have the same issue but for a child version in an already connected Org to the partners portal tech. I see the previous version, but not the child one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your 2GMP to listing in AppExchange and create at least one released version of 2GMP. Before you do that, you need to connect your dev hub org to your partner community portal.

Recently there was some problem with partner security portal scanner which didn't show any of package versions, but this has been fixed as of 1 September 2022.

Also alternative way to run Checkmarx scanner is to use Customer security portal.

Comment: What to do if I don't see a promoted to release child version? I have a released version 4.0.0.0 and I've started the security review for it, but I want to switch the 4.1.0.4 version I want to submit for review.

Comment: there might be some delay, if it doesn't come up for 24 hours, contact SF Support